# C# нарисовать таблицу в textBox (псевдографика)

Tags: c#, textbox

Приветсвтую. Есть задача отобразить таблицу в  компоненте textBox. Нужно, что бы таблица подстраивалась под содержимое. Я нашёл несколько готовых реализаций ([вот](https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/ConsoleTables) самая простая), но проблема в том, что они красиво отображают таблицу в консоле. Если эту таблицу перенести на TextBox, то разметка таблица уезжает. Я пытался как-то изменить метод ToString() класса из примера, но ни к чему хорошему это не привело. Может кто сталкивался с рисованием таблиц в textBox или подскажет как изменить этот класс, что бы он подружился и с TextBox, а не только с колнсолью? Спасибо.

Comment: поменяйте шрифт на моноширинный

Comment: Была такая мысль, но что-то я её сразу откинул. Спасибо, проблема решена!

Comment: @4per можете в ответе написать, почему данное решение сработает. И как это проявляеться. Буду благодарен

Comment: Блин, зачем такие извращения? Используйте какой-нибудь компонент грида и дело с концом.